# Magento 2 Product Listing Issue:- You cannot define a correlation name 'mp' more than once

Tags: magento2.2.4, join-table, product-listing

I'm trying to join custom table on product listing page,here is the Class and method:-

**Class:-** vendor/magento/module-catalog/Block/Product/ProductList/Toolbar.php

**Method:-** setCollection()

Here is the code of this method:-

```
 public function setCollection($collection)
    {
        $this->_collection = $collection;

       //My Custom Code

         $mpJoinConditions = 'mp.mageproduct_id = e.entity_id';

                       $this->_collection->getSelect()->join(
                ['mp' => $this->_collection->getTable('marketplace_product')],
                $mpJoinConditions,
                []
            )->columns("mp.seller_id");

       // End of My Custom Code

        $this->_collection->setCurPage($this->getCurrentPage());

        // we need to set pagination only if passed value integer and more that 0
        $limit = (int)$this->getLimit();
        if ($limit) {
            $this->_collection->setPageSize($limit);
        }
        if ($this->getCurrentOrder()) {
            $this->_collection->setOrder($this->getCurrentOrder(), $this->getCurrentDirection());
        }
        return $this;
    }
```

**But getting following issue:-**

**"You cannot define a correlation name 'mp' more than once"**

Please help me to resolve the issue!!!

Answer (score 0):

Used Tablename "marketplace_product" instead of using alias "mp" and it's working fine now.

Answer (score 0):

This is very odd, although `mp` was defined only once, I tried your solution but didn't work.